# iOS/swift - create calendar weekview

Tags: ios, calendar, swift2

I'm trying to create a **calendar weekview in portrait mode** in an iOS app. I only need 1 week that will be displayed all the time, so 7 columns are enough.

**To visualise**: the result should look something like the middle screen in this picture:
http://41.media.tumblr.com/a5bc39604e4cd0d6ebf036d204aff82e/tumblr_ncndmwmNKg1tlbw3mo3_1280.jpg

I'm fairly new to iOS. I can create some basic apps now but can't figure out how to design this view. 
**What controller and view should I start with?
Any ideas on how to design this view?**

Any help is very welcome! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this awesome library.. https://github.com/erichoracek/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout

Comment: It looks very neat. You don't know anything written in Swift? Otherwise I will need to learn O-C language.

Comment: have you found swift version?